# Для каких MIME-типов сервер должен определять кодировку (charset)?

Tags: php, html, http, mime, charset

W3C [пишут](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/) про текстовые типы, без каких либо пояснений:

> Documents transmitted with HTTP that are of **type text**, such as
>   text/html, text/plain, etc., can send a charset parameter in the HTTP
>   header to specify the character encoding of the document.

В частности интересуют MIME-типы:

- text/css
- text/xml
- image/svg+xml
- text/html
- text/plain
- application/json
- application/javascript
- image/png
- image/jpeg
- image/x-icon

Comment: это слишком общий вопрос. Даже для одного text/html можно много чего написать: разные [противоречащие] стандарты в течение лет, разная практика [разной степени популярности: что браузеры делают, что распространённые библиотеки, API, конфигурации развёрнутых решений, итд).

Comment: @jfs Ну хотя бы про эти три: `application/javascript`, `application/json` и `image/svg+xml`? С остальными типами в принципе более-менее понятно.

Comment: вот [для application/json вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13096259/4279)

Answer (score 0):

MIME-типы с поддержкой параметра charset:

- [text/html](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html)
- [text/plain](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046#section-4.1.2)
- [text/xml](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/xml)
- [text/css](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/css)
- [application/javascript](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/javascript)
- [image/svg+xml](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/mimereg.html)

MIME-типы без поддержки параметра charset:

- [application/json](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json)
- [image/png](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/png)
- [image/jpeg](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045)
- [image/x-icon](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/image/vnd.microsoft.icon)

Следуя общей [рекомендации](https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/#charset) W3C: *"It is very important to always label Web documents explicitly"* можно указать параметр charset для всех MIME-типов с его поддержкой.